# No com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity in the zxing core jar

Tags: android, zxing, barcode-scanner

I am currently trying to implement the barcode scanner using zxing. I found out that I have to add these code in the manifest:

```
        <activity
           android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity"
           android:screenOrientation="landscape"
           android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
           android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
           android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden">
           <intent-filter>
              <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
              <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
           </intent-filter>
           <intent-filter>
              <action android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN"/>
              <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
           </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

To do so, I have to add the zxing jar as a library to my project, which I have do so, by downloading the jar file from [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.zxing/core/2.2)

I have also put the jar in my libs directory, and add it as library. The problem is, there is no com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity directory in that jar file. There is only com.google.zxing.client.result.

The reason I wanted to use intent calling the zxing is that, somehow after a few tests, it is faster to detect qr code than using zxing's intentintegrator. Here is the snippet of the intent calling code.

```
            Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
            intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "QR_CODE_MODE");
            startActivityForResult(intent, SCAN_ACTIVITY);
```

Can anyone help me? thanks

NB: here is some tutorial references: [one](http://karanbalkar.com/2013/12/tutorial-65-implement-barcode-scanner-using-zxing-in-android/), [two](https://damianflannery.wordpress.com/2011/06/13/integrate-zxing-barcode-scanner-into-your-android-app-natively-using-eclipse/)

Comment: https://github.com/journeyapps/zxing-android-embedded add dependency

Comment: i also have tried to add dependencies before, actually it works, but I don't know why, it is harder to detect the qr code than directly using intent calling "com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN"